# Selecting difficulty on Dungeons of Dredmor

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor

For some reason, no matter what button I press on the difficulty screen on Dungeons of Dredmor, it automatically selects Dwarvish Moderation and Permadeath.  Doesn't matter where I click, or whether I press up or down, etc.  Hell, I can hit the back button and it moves to the Skill Select screen.  Has anybody else had this problem, and how do I solve it?

Comment: Thanks!  The mouse-over/mouse-wheel technique works really well.

Comment: Cool, glad it helped. I turned it into an actual answer below. I'd hesitated making it a "real" answer initially because I had no way to verify it.

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a problem that many users have had since the game's release, and there has not yet been an official fix.

[Here's one possible solution you might try.](http://community.gaslampgames.com/threads/cannot-choose-difficulty-settings-and-other-settings.1798/#post-15423)

> After some experimentation, I resolved the issue by floating my cursor over the settings and scrolling with the mousewheel to select or deselect options